# CSS cursor customization

Tags: html, css, cursor

I'm trying to make a CSS code that changes the cursor to a picture file when the cursor is on a webpage. I've seen sites that give you a simple code to do it but they always have ads. Any codes you guys know that can do this?

Comment: Just because you can change the cursor, doesn't always mean you should.  You can really irritate people using your site if you arbitrarily use a custom cursor.  Only do it if it makes sense to do so.

Comment: @pspain, actually I only intend for the members of my site to have this option. So they can have it on or off. I'm not just using it because.

Comment: The last question was about marquee and now this... I'm sorry but are you from the past?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, simply apply the following css code to your body tag (assuming you want effect for whole page):

```
body {
    cursor: url('URL to image');
}
```

Further information:
The image file must be 32x32 or smaller
Internet explorer only supports .cur files

Comment: I assuming that you changed "images/curesorimagesfile.gif" to an actual image file. Otherwise, as I edited above, Internet Explorer only accepts .cur files. What browser/operating system are you using?

Comment: If you are looking for software to create .cur files with, then I would recommend aniFX (http://icofx.ro/anifx/index.html)

Comment: @Nico Burns, I'm using FireFox 3.5 Windows Vista With service pack 2. I'm uising a 32 x 32 gif image in the home directory. And using the code you gave me. I'll check out the program to.

Answer (score 3):

CSS:

```
html{
  cursor: url(URL of pictures)
}
```

Other Simples:
http://www.html1.freeiz.com/Your_cursor.html
http://jsfiddle.net/wNKcU/5/
http://jsfiddle.net/wNKcU/788/

Answer (score -1):

create an HTML element with the cursor image you want and use javascript's onmousemove event to move the cursor.
`window.onmousemove= function(e) {cursor.left=e.x;cursor.top=e.y;} //cursor is the HTML element`