# How to make custom cursor on website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS cursor customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144836/css-cursor-customization)

I want the code for **changing cursor** on my site as it is given on the link below.

[Demo Here](http://www.freelancerseoconsultant.com/2013/01/facebook-introducing-new-graph-search.html)

I would also like to know how to do it. Please give a small code for this purpose.

Comment: While not an answer, this is a horrible example and you should stick with standards. If you have a special "Not allowed" symbol when hovering over a specific item, it's fine, but to have a cursor like this you might as well have the animated dinosaur cursors from old versions of Windows.

Answer (score 18):

You can use custom image by:

```
body, html {
    cursor: url(cursor.gif), pointer;
}
```

In `url` there's a path to the cursor image.

The cursor property may contain comma separated values of the allowed options: `cursor: url(cursor.gif), url(cursor1.gif), pointer;`.

An example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q94EV/).

**Note**: always specify at least one generic cursor in case that a URL-defined cursor can not be provided.

Comment: Where to write this code? In CSS?

Comment: Is there any way to "move" the image? e.g. make the center of image be a cursor point?

Comment: No. You have to use a trick to do that. Make the cursor image transparent and just translate the image to not be in the center.

Comment: I love that @MinkoGechev (more or less Angular Celeb) answered this js cursor question lulz.

Comment: Notice that cursor image can't be larger than 128x128 pixels.

Answer (score 2):

In the CSS file you have to add a property on body tag as following:

```
    body{
        cursor: anything like(pointer,default etc.)
    }
```

If you want exactly same cursor as given in the site by you, then do as follow:

```
    cursor: url("http://safir85.ucoz.com/24work-blogspot/mouse-cursor/COOL_BLUE_OUTER_GLOW_POINTER-www.24work.blogspot.c.cur"), progress;
```

Think it will help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a css property for this: `cursor`. See in action in [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=url%28smiley.gif%29,url%28myBall.cur%29,auto).