# is it possible to create a custom cursor from glyphicon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, glyphicons

I was wondering if custom cursor can be made from glyphicon. one way i can think of is to make cursor property none over body. Set the glyphicon z-index to top most with absolute positioning based on jquery mousemove x,y coordinates. is this the right way or is there any native methods ?

Comment: anything you tried till now?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144836/css-cursor-customization

Comment: it would be simpler to make screenshot images of the icons, and use a bitmap mouse cursor. you MAY be able to do it all fancy and use html2canvas to produce the image on-the-fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although i did not find the native way to do this. 
But [here's](https://jsfiddle.net/cpLtvueb/) how i did it with jquery and css property.

```
#test{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    cursor:none;
    background-color:#ff0000;
}

#mycur{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1000;
    cursor:none;
}

$("#test").mousemove(function(e){
    mycur=$("#mycur");
    mycur.css("left",e.offsetX);
    mycur.css("top",e.offsetY);
});

<div id="test">
</div>
<i id="mycur" class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>
```